# How to have an InvocableVariable appear as Drop Down List in Process Builder

Tags: apex, process-builder, invocable-method, invocablevariable

**BACKGROUND**

I have a class with an `InvocableMethod` which takes a set of `InvocableVariable`'s

Such that I can call the Apex class from **Process Builder**.

**QUESTION**

I would like one of the fields to appear as a **dropdown** list of options when configuring within Process Builder.

**ATTEMPTS**

I have tried setting the `InvocableVariable` type as a custom class:

```
global class TestType { 

    public final String VALUE_ONE = 'one';
    public final String VALUE_TWO = 'two';

}
```

And I have tried setting the `InvocableVariable` type as an `Enum`:

```
public enum Season 
{
    WINTER, 
    SPRING, 
    SUMMER, 
    FALL
}
```

Both give me an error of:

> InvocableVariable fields do not support type of XXX

How do I define the `InvocableVariable` such that I can pick from a set of options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible.

> The invocable variable can’t be one of the following:
>
> - A type such as an interface, class, or enum.
> - A non-member variable such as a static or local variable.
> - A property. A final variable. Protected or private.
>
> The data type of the invocable variable must be one of the following:
>
> - A primitive data type or a list of a primitive data type – the generic Object type is not supported.
> - An sObject type or a list of an sObject type – the generic sObject type is not supported.

Reference:

- [Apex Developer Guide: InvocableVariable Annotation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableVariable.htm)

Answer (score 1):

So, one option would be to define (or reuse an existing) Sobject `Foo__c` with a custom picklist field that has the value set you care about.

```
Seasons__c type picklist with values SPRING, ...
```

Then have the invocable method support a list of `Foo__c` as the argument. This will provide the dropdown values you need.

Comment: @Robs -- Have the PB invoke a Visual Flow that in turn calls the invocableApex using custom Sobject Foo__c. VisualFlow supports choosing from existing picklist values in the Assignment operation

Answer (score 1):

@Robs i am not sure if you manage to find best possible solution.

I use to do like this, so at least user know possible values for the parameter.

```
    @InvocableVariable(label='Season' description='Type one of these WINTER, SPRING, SUMMER, FALL' required=true)
    public String season;
```